# Meteor Collection insert method not found

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am creating my first meteor project. I am trying to use autoform to insert data to a collection. I notice that collection does not seem to be publishing and I get this error when I try submit the form .

```
errorClass {error: 404, reason: "Method '/recipes/insert' not found", details: undefined, message: "Method '/recipes/insert' not found [404]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

I am trying to follow the recommend application structure.

**imports/api/lists/recipes.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Recipes = new Mongo.Collection('recipes');

Recipes.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
        return (userId && doc.owner === userId);
    },
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only remove your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    fetch: ['owner']
});

RecipeSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description"
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author",
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created At",
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
});

Recipes.attachSchema( RecipeSchema );
```

**imports/api/lists/server/publish.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Recipes } from '../recipes.js';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // This code only runs on the server
  Meteor.publish('recipes', function(){
    console.log('Published')
    return recipes.find({author: this.userId});
  });
}else{
    console.log("Not server");
}
```

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '../imports/api/lists/server/publish.js';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

**imports/ui/layouts/recipes/newRecipe.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Recipes } from '../../../api/lists/recipes.js';

import './newRecipe.html'


Template.NewRecipe.helpers({
    formCollection() {
        return Recipes;
    }
});
```

**imports/ui/layouts/recipes/newRecipe.html**

```
<template name="NewRecipe">
    <div id="new-recipe-container">
        {{> quickForm collection=formCollection id="insertRecipeForm" type="insert" class="new-recipe-form"}}
    </div>
</template>
```

IF any one could help me out let me know where im am going wrong would be great. 
Thanks

Comment: In publish.js . You have written recipes instead of Recipes.

Comment: Hey Ankit thanks a million